# Is the singular form of "desiderata" a disused word?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, latin

I was interested in the following paragraph which appeared in an article titled “[A New Gauge to See What’s Beyond Happiness](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/05/17/science/17tierney.html?_r=1)" by John Tierney in The New York Times (May 16, 2011).

> “They wanted to win for its own sake, even if it brought no positive
>   emotion,” says Dr. Seligman, a professor of psychology at the
>   University of Pennsylvania. “They were like hedge fund managers who
>   just want to accumulate money and toys for their own sake. Watching
>   them play, seeing them cheat, it kept hitting me that accomplishment
>   is *a human desiderata* in itself.” *[emphasize mine]*

Can someone clarify if the fragment "a human desiderata" is "simply" ungrammatical, as I think it is, or if the problem consist in the fact that the singular form of "desiderata", that is *desideratum*, is a disused word?

Is it possible to argue the latter hypothesis from the [nGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=desiderata%2Cdesideratum&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=2) below?

[image]

---

[Oxford
Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/desideratum?region=us&q=desideratum) - "**desideratum**: noun (plural desiderata)"

Comment: I think this Ngram might mean that *desiderata* is [turning into](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+desiderata+is%2Cthe+desiderata+are%2Cthe+desideratum+is&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=7) a mass noun, rather than a plural, possibly like [criteria](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+criteria+is%2Cthe+criteria+are%2Cthe+criterion+is%2C+a+criteria+is&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=7). But I don't believe "a desiderata" is grammatical yet. Both "a criteria" and "a desiderata" are still very rare.

Answer (score 6):

- 'a desiderata' is not formally correct in English (or 'unum desiderata' in Latin), because 'desideratum' is singular in English (as it is in Latin)
- borrowings from other languages aren't necessarily bound to the inflections of the source language (sometimes the rule goes with the source language, and other times with target, English)
- as to actual practice, I would think the better, more appropriate nGram comparison would be [between 'a desiderata' and 'a desideratum'](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+desiderata%2C+a+desideratum&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=2):

[image: comparison of a des...um' and 'a des...a']

which shows that 'a desideratum' is only waning in usage. 'a desiderata' does occur (by looking at the [nGram for it by itself](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+desiderata&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=2)) but errors do occur.

Comment: You can run it with *these* vs *this* in front of *desiderata*.  The former is overwhelmingly more frequent.  Don’t try *those* vs *that*, though, due to false positives from *that* as a relative pronoun.